# Can anyone explain how to calculate Gaussian and mean curvatures using B-Spline fit method?

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to calculate Gaussian and mean curvatures of some real surface which is from some RGB-D
camera like Kinect. So there is no a expression of this real surface. How to calculate the Gaussian and mean curvatures of it? A paper said using 3x3 B-Spline surfaces to fit the original surface then calculate it. Can anyone give a detailed example ? or some matlab code?

Comment: I suggest you will give much attention on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the form of your data.